# Switching an existing JSF Project from Windows to MacOS

Tags: java, eclipse, macos, tomcat, jsf

I create a JSF Project on my Surface Book (Win 10 Pro) and switched recently to a Mac Book Pro. As I imported the project I saw something strange:

The project structure in Eclipse EE on Windows looks like this:

[image: Project structure on Windows]

and on MacOS (also using Eclipse EE) like this.
[image: Project structure on MacOS]

It looks like there went something wrong at importing the projects. I can also not start the server at all. (Actually JSF cannot find any beans on Mac while everything works perfectly fine on Windows) BTW: I use TomCat 8.5 as application server.

Comment: Just couple thoughts: Make sure that they are the same version of Eclipse. Also make sure you mark folders as source if they need to be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it now with a workaround. I still don't know what went wrong but here is my solution:

I just created a new JSF Project and pasted all of my stuff (sources, resources, etc.) into it, and it worked. (some minor configurations will probably be needed)